# Error Variable does not exist, get value from class in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

I want to get the return value from my  class to my trigger but get the error Variable does not exist: currentUser?

Class

```
public class NavigateToContpersOpl {
    @AuraEnabled
public static String getLoggedInUser(){

        User ContactUser =[SELECT Id, ContactId FROM User WHERE Id =:UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
        system.debug('ContactUser.ContactId '+ ContactUser.ContactId);
        Contactpersoon_Opleiding__c currentUser = new Contactpersoon_Opleiding__c();
        List<Contactpersoon_Opleiding__c> currentUserList = [SELECT Id, Contactpersoon__c  FROM  Contactpersoon_Opleiding__c WHERE Contactpersoon__c=:ContactUser.ContactId LIMIT 1];

       system.debug('currentUserList '+ currentUserList);

        if(currentUserList.size() > 0){
        currentUser  = currentUserList[0];
            system.debug('currentUser.Id '+ currentUser.Id);
            return currentUser.Id;
        }else{
            return 'NULL';
        }
    }

}
```

Trigger

```
trigger RelatieContPreFill on Relatie_Contact__c (before insert) {

    NavigateToRelatieController n = new NavigateToRelatieController();
    Id ContactIdFromClass;
    ContactIdFromClass = n.returnState(currentUser);

    for (Relatie_Contact__c  Rc : Trigger.new){
        if(trigger.isBefore){
       ..  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it is not defined...where in your trigger do you see anything that would lead you to believe you can reference a variable named `currentUser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the method. As your method does not accept any parameter so you don't need to send anything. As this is static method so you need to call it using class name and don't need to create any instance.

```
Id ContactIdFromClass  = NavigateToRelatieController .getLoggedInUser();
```

Second thing

```
if(currentUserList.size() > 0){
        currentUser  = currentUserList[0]; //currentUserList is type of Contactpersoon_Opleiding__c object while currentUser  is of user type so you will get exception here

return currentUserList[0].Id; //you can do like this
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your method from within a trigger:

```
NavigateToContpersOpl.getLoggedInUser();
```

No need to instantiate the class since your method is a static method.

Since your question relates only to the trigger context, you do not need to annotate the method with @AuraEnabled.  The reason for the undefined variable exception is that you never declare a variable called currentUser in your code.

I would suggest taking a read through the [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm) and the [Intro to Apex trail on Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_intro).